# how to display php unicode charaters

Tags: php, unicode

**php unicode charaters shows** `à®†à®£à¯à®•à®³à¯`

eg: [image]

the treatment data is is shows correctly but gender category and Diseases data s not shows correctly the image shows my output, how to solve this please hep.

**code is:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../library/css/style.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".update_input").hide();

  $("#edit").click(function(){
  $("#danger").hide();
  $(".help-block").hide();
  $(".update_input").show();
  $("#update").show();
  });

  $("#update").click(function(){
  $(".update_input").hide();
  $("#update").hide();
  $(".help-block").show();

  });

  $("#danger").click(function(){
var id = $(".hiden_id").attr('id');
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"+id))
{
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(e)
{
window.location.href="all_pages.php"; 
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
           });
    return false;
}
});


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
if($_GET["id"]==""){
    $_GET["id"] = $_SESSION['trid'];
}
 else {
    $_SESSION['trid']=$_GET["id"];
}

?>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql2.000webhost.com","a3821029_admin","abc123","a3821029_ayurved");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  if(!$_GET["id"]==""){


$Treatment_id = $_SESSION['trid'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT gender_id, diseases_id, Treatments_type, image FROM treatment WHERE Tid = '$Treatment_id'");
$row_gid = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$gender = $row_gid['gender_id'];
$diseases = $row_gid['diseases_id'];
$Treatments_type = $row_gid['Treatments_type'];
$image = $row_gid['image'];

$select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT category FROM gender WHERE id = '$gender'");
$select_gender = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
$Gender_name = $select_gender['category'];

$sl_dise = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Diseases_type FROM diseases WHERE id = '$diseases'");
$row_did = mysqli_fetch_array($sl_dise);
$diseases_value = $row_did['Diseases_type'];


}

else{
    header('Location: ./all_pages.php');
}
?>

    <div class="container">
            <div class="selection_container">
                <div class="page-header">

  <h1><img src="../resources/images/leaf_green.gif" class="adminpanel_icons">Ayurvedic Web Portal</h1>
</div>
<a href="all_pages.php">Back to view all_pages</a>


                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="update_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="tablecox">

                <table style="" class="" id="update_table">

                    <input type="hidden" name="tid" class="hiden_id" value="<?php echo $Treatment_id;?>" id="<?php echo $Treatment_id;?>"></input>
  <tr>
      <td style="width: 30%; text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;">Gender category</td>
    <td style="width: 70%;">
        <span class="help-block" id="gender_span"><?php echo $Gender_name; ?></span>

            <select name="gender" class="update_input" id="gender_input">

                <option value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">Select</option>
                <option value="10">Male</option>
                <option value="11">Female</option>
                <option value="12">Childs</option>
                <option value="13">Childrens</option>
                <option value="14">Elderly people</option>
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 30%; text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;">Diseases</td>
    <td>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $diseases_value; ?></span>
        <input type="text" name="disease" class="update_input" id="disease_update" value="<?php echo $diseases_value; ?>">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 30%; text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;">Treatment</td>
    <td>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $Treatments_type; ?></span>
        <textarea class="update_input" name="treatment" id="treatment_update" rows="8"><?php echo $Treatments_type; ?></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td style="width: 30%; text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="../uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" style=" max-height: 200px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

            <input type="file" class="update_input" id="exampleInputFile" name="userfile" value=""/>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
                </div>
                <br>
<button class="btn" id="edit" type="button">Edit</button>
<input class="btn" id="update" type="submit" name="submit" value="update">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="danger">Delete</button>

    </form>
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the treatment data is is shows correctly but gender category and Diseases data s not shows correctly the image shows my output, how to solve this please hep.

Comment: Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Yes, you need to use `mysqli_set_charset` and make sure your tables are stored in a UTF-8 collation. But your security problems are worse than your Unicode problems. You have HTML-injection (use `htmlspecialchars` every time you echo content in HTML!), you have SQL injection (use `mysqli_prepare`/`mysqli_stmt_bind_param` instead of putting strings inside queries), you have hard-coded database creds (keep them in a separate file outside the web root), you have no apparent access control or CSRF protection.

Comment: I used mysqli_set_charset, 1st 2datas are not show correctly that database type is MyISAM, treatment is show correctly that data type is innodb. so MyISAM is a problem. please help anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use MySQLi you should use the MySQLi charset command, instead of the old MySQL charset:

`mysqli_set_charset ( $con , 'utf8' )`

Comment: Note that MySQL's `utf8` charset is broken and you should probably use [`utf8mb4`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).